# Add text from user input to an image [imagettftext]

Tags: php, imagettftext

Trying to find a way of doing this, but going round in circles.

What we are trying to achieve is like [this](http://www.hetemeel.com/einsteinform.php)

I have read up on :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

and

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

I am just going round in circles. I am trying to have a preloaded image on page. Allow user to type text into a text box. Click Preview, and then they can see Image with the text on top.

But rather than the image be served as somepicture.php or myimage.png?text=foo I wanted it to write the image ( new ) to the server and be saved as something like userpic_123.png

Does anyone know of or can point me in the right direction, in scripting this correctly please.

Our objective ( quick scribble I made )
[image]

Comment: We're you ale to solve this? How?

Answer (score 0):

after you've processed your image with imagettftext you simply can save it with Imagejpeg by passing the image as first parameter and then the path to file where to save.

```
$filename="/image_path/user_".time().".jpeg";
Imagejpeg($im, $filename, 100);
```